# Download file from page that makes you wait using RCurl

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I want to download a file from a page that makes me wait for the download. Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74337) an example of curl code would be:

```
curl -O -J -L   http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.1/bitcoin-0.8.1-linux.tar.gz/download
```

which does what I want from the terminal. Now I want to do this using `RCurl` in R, but I have no idea where to start...

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (using `httr` which is a modern wrapper for `RCurl`):

```
library(httr)

url <- "http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.3/bitcoin-0.8.3-linux.tar.gz/download"
dl <- GET(url, write_disk("bitcoin-0.8.3-linux.tar.gz"), verbose())
```

The `verbose()` is purely for interactive debugging and can be removed.